# Is my GAE Search corrupt?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

I've got a single index in a GAE Search application.

When I call `index.put` I get the `OverQuotaError: The API call search.IndexDocument() required more quota than is available.`

When I got to the GAE Console and look under Search then my index `articleIndex` contains no documents but its `Amount Used` is 78.2KB. I've also tried retrieving documents but none are returned.

I've tried using a new index but I can the same error message in my application's logs.

I have a copy of my application and that continues to work fine - this uses the same code and data but in a separate application space.

I created a new app with the code from my "corrupted" installation and the new installation indexes fine.

Has anyone had a GAE Search index that, although empty, is listed as taking up space?

I've tried running my GAE routines right after my daily quota is renewed ([image: image attached]).

Answer (score 1):

The quota representing storage usage is reconciled nightly, so if you have recently removed documents from the index that fact will not immediately be reflected.  However, you say that using a new index still produces the same problem?

Note that daily quota renewal (not to be confused with the reconciliation mentioned above) does not affect the storage limit.

If you are still having troubles, you can file a report on the external issue tracker, mention the app ID and index name, and we can help investigate the current status of the index.

Comment: thanks @Alan I've posted an issue here with my app details at its foot: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13068&thanks=13068&ts=1465911775